# how to do registration using json url in iOS that is POST

Tags: objective-c, web-services, http-post, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

hi i am new for iOS Programming please help, and the code is related to webservices using the below link i want to past username,password and other related fields into server

```
    //in this method i am doing URLconnection 

        -(void)ConnectionValid
                {
                    NSString *username=userTxtField.text;
                    NSString *pass=passTxtField.text;
                    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http:indian.azurewebsites.net/api/values/registration?type=registration&Username=%@&password=%@&favcolor=&agreement=isChecked",username,pass];
                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
                    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
         {
            if (error) 
            {
                // Handle error
                [self handleError:error];
            } 
            else
            {
                [self parseJSONResponse:data];
            }

        }];


        }
    //it handle error alert
        -(void)handleError:(NSError *)error
        {
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")
                                                              message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [message show];
        }
//it is parsing json
        -(void)parseJSONResponse:(NSData*)responseData
        {
            NSError *err;
            NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
        }
```

please help me i am new for objective c programming, thanks in advance..........

Comment: Did you try running the code? Are you seeing some sort of error? I think we need a bit more information here before we can help.

Comment: sry for the delay reply. ya i got an error your request is timed out. @sid

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you are trying to post a request to the server and get json response as a result. then try the below code.

```
  NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:indian.azurewebsites.net/api/values/registration"];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *params=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"type=registration&Username=%@&password=%@&favcolor=&agreement=isChecked",username,pass];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           //Do stuff here
                                                       }

                                                   }];
[dataTask resume];}
```